# R help - change the maximum value of each row in a certain condition

Tags: r

I am in a novice of R. I have a dataframe with columns 1:n.  *Excluding column 1 and n*, I want to change the maximum value of each row if the row has a specific value in a different column AND set the remaining values (excluding column 1 and n) to zero. I have about 300,000 cases and 40 columns in my real data, however, the example below illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
A <- c(1,1,5,5,10)
B <- rnorm(1:5)
C <- rnorm(1:5)
D <- rnorm(1:5)
E <- c(10,15,100,100,100)
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
df

   A           B          C          D   E
1  1  0.74286670  0.3222136  0.9381296  10
2  1 -0.03352498  0.5262685  0.1225731  15
3  5 -0.17689629 -0.8949740 -1.4376567 100
4  5  0.48329153  1.1574834 -1.1116581 100
5 10  0.13117277 -0.2068736  0.4841806 100
```

Here, if column A of each row has 1, I want to change the maximum value of each row into the value of column E, and set columns B, C and D to 0.

So, the result should be like this:

```
   A           B          C          D   E
1  1           0          0         10  10
2  1           0         15          0  15
3  5 -0.17689629 -0.8949740 -1.4376567 100
4  5  0.48329153  1.1574834 -1.1116581 100
5 10  0.13117277 -0.2068736  0.4841806 100
```

I tried to do this for two days. Thanks.

Comment: What's happening with row 2 in column C - is that part of your question or just something we can ignore?

Comment: It should be considered. row 2 in column C has the largest value (0.5262685) in row 2. So the value should be changed into row 2 column E value (15). Thank you very much.

Comment: You may wish to add e.g. `set.seed(42)` before your code and regenerate your output.  That will make the 'random' output the same for everyone when they  run your sample code.

Comment: Is your actual data only 5 columns wide, or is it wider with your real data?

Comment: I appologize my mistake due to an immature skill. I have data of 300,000 rows and 40 columns.

Comment: Not at all: Your example is very good.  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out and see what happens :)

```
df <- read.table(text = "A B C D E
1  1  0.74286670  0.3222136  0.9381296  10
2  1 -0.03352498  0.5262685  0.1225731  15
3  5 -0.17689629 -0.8949740 -1.4376567 100
4  5  0.48329153  1.1574834 -1.1116581 100
5 10  0.13117277 -0.2068736  0.4841806 100", stringsAsFactor = FALSE)

# find the max in columns B,C,D
z <- apply(df[df$A == 1, 2:4], 1, max)

# substitute the maximum value of each row for columns B,C,D where A == 1
# with the value of column E. Assign 0 to the others
y <- ifelse(df[df$A == 1, 2:4] == z, df$E[df$A == 1], 0)

# Change the values in your dataframe
df[df$A == 1, 2:4] <- y
```

Comment: I am sorry for my late reply. It works very well. I really appreciate your advice. And I add another way to change the value what I found, but my one is instable. 


df[df$A == 1,2:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df[df$A == 1,3:20])), apply(df[df$A == 1,2:4], 1, which.max))] <- df[df$A == 1, "E"]